# Trying to get property 'title' of non-object - in laravel

Tags: laravel

when trying to view a specific blog article i get the error Trying to get property 'title' of non-object
here is my controller controller code

```
  public function theblog(Request $req, $slug){
    $blog = blog::find($slug);
    DB::table("blogs")->where('slug', "$slug")->increment('views');
    return view('myblog',compact('blog'));  
}
```

Comment: Before`DB::...` line, write `dd($blog);` to see/debug what you have there.

Comment: you would have to actually show the code that is trying to access the property `title` on something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  public function theblog(Request $req, $slug){
    $blog = blog::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();
    DB::table("blogs")->where('slug', $slug)->increment('views');
    return view('myblog',compact('blog'));  
}
```

Some tips.

- your primary key is unlikely to be 'slug' so you need to use a where
- don't quote php parameters
- your classes should start with an uppercase, ie Blog not blog
- you should probably only increment views once per user

Answer (score 0):

```
public function theblog(Request $req, $slug){ $blog = blog::find($slug);
dd($slug); 
 DB::table("blogs")->where('slug', "$slug")->increment('views'); return view('myblog',compact('blog')); }
```

Check if there is value for $blog...if it is null(that is the problem)  then you should check you DB?